# which best practice for designing MySQL database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to design a database for a hospital management system
I have in the system: Doctors, Nurses, patients, accountants, department, and booking .....

what is the best practice for design: first option: user_info table contain: ID, name, age, user_type .....

second option: doctors_table contain : ID, name, age ....., patients_table contain : ID, name, age .....,

third option: you can suggest another one

Comment: What is the system going to manage? Finances? Operations? Organ donations?

Comment: manage healthcare operations  and finances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the fields are the same, then use one table (option one) and add a `type` field for if they are doctor, accountant, etc.

You can then also have other tables for specific fields that you join, based on those type fields.

Comment: what about if doctors and staff have a special department and patients haven't

Comment: Then add a special department table with the userid of the person mining it's linked to.